# What software program do most use in the health sciences for preparing paper for submission to journal?

Tags: paper-submission

I am submiting my first paper for publication without any academic setting or advisor.  What software programs do researchers/writers use to submit papers for publication?

Comment: Why do you have no advisor? Has your research been approved by an appropriate body like an institutional review board?

Comment: This depends at least partly on the field. Some journals have preferred formats for submittal.

Comment: Probably MS Word, but each journal will have their own template and formatting requirements. LaTeX and Markdown are seldom used outside of Math/CS. However, some journal publishers have non-Word templates.

Comment: Those using binary... :)